# Is it possible to move a Wordpress Blog Database to a Rails Database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, wordpress, port, migrate

I am in the process of creating a new website using the Rails framework. I would like to migrate the old blog posts from Wordpress into the new site. My initial thought is to get the blog database and migrate it to Rails using mysql. What would be the best way to take this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that WordPress allows admins to export there blog posts as xml files.

My solution:

Export as xml 
Convert to JSON (for readability) 
Create fields relative to JSON 
Seed